# Jwplayer subtitles and resolution

Tags: javascript, html, jwplayer

Iam want the way to add subtitles and resolution options in my Jwpalyer
code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Note: JW Player 7 now requires a license key. Please make sure to include this on your page if you are self-hosting.
    //jwplayer.key = "Ywok59g9j93GtuSU7+axNzjIp/TBfiK4s0vvYg==";
    var videoPlayer = jwplayer('my_video').setup({
        file: 'http://content.jwplatform.com/videos/IMUjQRAB-kNspJqnJ.mp4',
        image:'http://assets-jpcust.jwpsrv.com/thumbs/F5K02Tmh-720.jpg',
        width: '640',
        height: 360,
        //autostart: true,
        skin: {
            name: "flat"
        },
        //timeSliderAbove: true,
        //Adding your brand: Logo & Right-click
        logo: {
            file: './jw-logo/logo_flat.png',
            logoBar: './jw-logo/logo_bar.png',
            position: 'top-left',
            link: 'http://codecanyon.net/user/facetheme'
        },
        abouttext: "Flat Skin Retina for JW7",
        aboutlink: "http://codecanyon.net/user/facetheme",
    });
    videoPlayer.on('ready',function() {
        jwLogoBar.addLogo(videoPlayer);
    });
</script>
```

I searched a lot but could not find enough answers and I hope to get enough answers here

Comment: For multiple resolution options, add the files which are different resolutions. As for the subtitles... [always read the plaque](https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1407438-adding-closed-captions).

Comment: thanks how to add  files which are different resolutions

Comment: Have you read their documentation?

Comment: Yas Iam now find  jast  tracks

Comment: https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-player/docs/developer-guide/customization/configuration-reference/#quality-toggle-for-video-files - search for quality toggle

Comment: Thank but when i add the  quality the subtitles switch  hide

Comment: Please check their support documents. It's likely that you need to add the subtitles for each resolution.

Comment: Thanks you i solve it